# no response on mysql using express

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, routes

I have a code that will query the user's table in the database, the problem is that after I query, there's no logs in the mysql's connect function and just skip the entire function after the query script

This is my code of connecting to the MySQL database

```
'user strict';

var mysql = require('mysql');

//local mysql db connection
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: '8000',
    user: 'homestead',
    password: 'secret',
    database: 'dbname'
});

connection.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
        throw err;
    }
});

export default connection;
```

and this is my route that I call when performing a http request to the server

```
let api = Router();

    api.post('/migrate', (req, res) => {

        mysqlDB.query("SELECT * FROM user", (error, data, fields) => {
            console.log('no log here...') // <---------------- no log appear here
            if (error) {
                console.log(error)
            } else {
                console.log(data)
            }
        })

        res.send('some response')
    });
```

I try to execute a INSERT query but the same thing happened, no logs and no data was inserted to the database.

I want to log the data inside my database but it just didn't show anything, what can I do to make it appear?

my database was running on `localhost:8000` and the data of the `user` table in the `dbname` database have a value in it.

Comment: are you requiring the connection after exporting it? your `mysqlDB` isn't it exported from connection?

Comment: @MavishA I'm importing it by `import mysqlDB from '../path_to_my_connection'`